# Data to be exported into excel form from mysql database tables

Tags: mysql, excel

There is an excel form, with some n number of fields in it. We need to pull data into the form from mysql database. Data will have to come into the form from different tables of the database. Please advise the approach to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!
Krishna

Comment: Did you try phpexcel?

Comment: Yes, I'm using phpexcel and it is having excellent Classes. Since, I'm very new to PHP coding, still facing some challenges. I've my .xls stored in my localdrive, which has n number of fields in the cells, i.e., 

A1 - NAME 
A2- EMAIL ADDRESS 
A3- PHONE NUMBER 
A4- DEPARTMENT 

I need to fetch data from mysql db and data need to be loaded into the cells 
B1, B2, B3, B4 for the above respective fields. Please advise with your suggestions. Thanks, Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is tightly connected into PHP. Use php to:
1. connect to mysql
2. read the data
3. arrange the data using comma
4. write the data into file.
5. name the file with extension .CSV

CSV (comma separated value) can be read by excel, without formatting of course.

Comment: Hi Martin,Thanks for the quick reply. I'm pretty new to PHP and your help will be much appreciated if you can explain me each step you mentioned above and is it possible to map the data coming from mysql tables into the form fields which are there in excel form. Please advise..Thanks, Krishna

Comment: Khrisna, you will need a tutorial on how to connect php to mysql. It's quite easy, but different slightly from case to case. Please google it and you will find lots of clear example. Also, my suggestion above is basically exporting mysql data into a text file (CSV). Excel can read CSV into each cells, just like normal excel file, but with no formatting / formula, just data. So it's not connecting automatically from mysql to excel.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using Zend please use mysql function to achieve the same. 
It will prompt to  download and save the excel. Its used to construct only one column and respective data. You can modify the script to add more columns and data.

```
$query = "select domain from site"; 
$rows = $dbcon->query($query)->fetchAll();
$csv_output = "website\r\n"; //header 
foreach($rows as $row) { 
$csv_output .= $row['domain']."\r\n"; 
} 
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header('Content-disposition: filename='.$filename.'.csv');
print $csv_output;
```

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your valid suggestion. Now I'm at least able to pull values from mysql db into a new excel sheet. I got to know phpexecl provides excellent classes for this kind of challenges. But I'm still not able to insert data into the existing excel form present in my local drive. If somebody can help me what I need to do  to write into the existing excel form. Thanks, Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Both Excel and esCalc can access data from mysql. But if you don't want to write SQL statements, esCalc is a good choice. Becuase esCalc can access data from different tables and join them which Excel can't. Here is an example: http://www.raqsoft.com/calculate-through-multi-table-join.html